# ContourPlot and inequalitie plot together

Tags: matlab, plot

Im new to matlab and I want to plot a ContourPlot together with two inequalities but I dont know how. The function that I want to plot its ContourPlot is something like this:

```
Z = (X-2).^2 + (Y-1).^2;
```

and here are the two inequalities:

```
ineq1 = X.^2 - Y <= 2;
ineq2 = X + Y <= 2;
```

this is what I have dodne so far:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-4:.2:4,-4:.2:4);
Z = (X-2).^2 + (Y-1).^2;

[C,h] = contour(X,Y,Z);
clabel(C,h)

ineq1 = X.^2 - Y <= 2;
ineq2 = X + Y <= 2;

range = (-4:.2:4);


hold on

plot(range,ineq1, range, ineq2)

hold off
```

but this does not feel right.

What I want to do is to visualize an optimization problem. First I want to plot the ContourPlot of the function and then the possible areas in that same plot, It would be great if I could show the intersection areas too.

[image]

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with `hold on; plot(); hold off;`?

Comment: I dont actualy know. Let me post the output here

Comment: And why is that image wrong?

Comment: I dont understand it, Iv ploted the two inequalities via wolframalpha and its something like this(http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=X^2+-+Y+%3C%3D+2+%2C+X+%2B+Y+%3C%3D+2%3B), I want a shape like this inside the ContourPlot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to draw the boundaries of the inequalities onto the contour plot, you can do this with [`line`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/line.html).

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-4:.2:4,-4:.2:4);
Z = (X-2).^2 + (Y-1).^2;

[C,h] = contour(X,Y,Z);
clabel(C,h)

x_vect = (-4:.05:4);
y_ineq1 = x_vect.^2 - 2;
y_ineq2 = 2 - x_vect;
line(x_vect, y_ineq1);
line(x_vect, y_ineq2);
```

Coloring the intersection area is a bit more tricky, and I'm not sure if it's exactly what you want to do, but you could look into using [`patch`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html), something like

```
% Indexes of x_vect, y_ineq1 and y_ineq2 for region where both satisfied:
region_indexes = find(y_ineq1<y_ineq2);
region_indexes_rev = region_indexes(end:-1:1);

% To plot this area need to enclose it 
% (forward along y_ineq1 then back along y_ineq2)
patch([x_vect(region_indexes),x_vect(region_indexes_rev)],...
      [y_ineq1(region_indexes),y_ineq2(region_indexes_rev)],...
      [1 0.8 1]) % <- Color as [r g b]

% May or may not need following line depending on MATLAB version to set the yaxes
ylim([-4 4])

% Get the original plot over the top
hold on
[C,h] = contour(X,Y,Z);
clabel(C,h)
hold off
```

[image: Matlab line and patch example]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first code runs just fisne, But when I try to run the second code matlab gives me: Undefined function or variable 'Indexes'.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought I'd checked it first. Should work better now.